# Datomic error message

Tags: clojure, datomic

I'm getting this when I'm calling transact:

`datomic.impl.Exceptions$IllegalArgumentExceptionInfo: :db.error/not-a-data-function Not a data function: 71
    data: {:db/error :db.error/not-a-data-function}
             java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: :db.error/not-a-data-function Not a data function: 71`

What is the error message trying to tell me? I don't have '71' in my data anywhere, so ah, um... Yeah. This takes clojure stack traces to a new level.

Comment: What was your datomic query?

Comment: Can you provide the contents of your call to transact?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Datomic supports database functions. So let's say you installed a database function called ":foo/bar" you would call it in a transaction thusly:

`[[:foo/bar arg1 arg2 ...]]`

What this error is saying is that it thinks you are calling a database function, but that function does't exist. In this case it thinks that function name is `71`.

Take a look at the data you are transacting and make sure it is in the correct format. For example, I've seen this error when passing a map as `{:my/key 42}` instead of `[{:my/key 42}]`. The input of transact should always be a sequence of data, even if all you are transacting is a hashmap.

Comment: Yeah. It was something like this. I was doing something stupid which caused the wrong data to be sent into transact.